# Stackoverflow when trying to run the Text example in the AndEngineExampleLauncher

Tags: android, andengine

Hey Game Engine Folks,

This is a question for those who worked with AndEngine for Android.

I've a problem getting the Text example of the AndEngineExampleLauncher working!

It throws the following exception:

```
09-30 10:11:19.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 10:11:19.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-30 10:11:19.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.getFontManager(BaseGameActivity.java:137)
09-30 10:11:19.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.getFontManager(BaseGameActivity.java:137)
09-30 10:11:19.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.getFontManager(BaseGameActivity.java:137)
```

I've googled that error and it seems that some other guys having the same problem, but I couldn't find a solution posted anywhere!

Have anybody been able to get this example working without getting this 80's & 90's StackOverflowError!.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Mohamed A.Karim

Comment: Add the code what you are trying...

Comment: @LalitPoptani I'm just trying to get the AndEngineExample running, no code from my side. Example source code is: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very odd, but I took the time to debug the AndEngine BaseGameActivity.java class from the AndEngine src and I've found the cause of the problem:

Here is the shipped with getFontManger() method:

```
    public FontManager getFontManager() {
    return this.getFontManager();
}
```

This is the typical StackOverFlow cause... The very classic one.

I've changed that method to be:

```
    public FontManager getFontManager() {
    return this.mEngine.getFontManager();
}
```

And the AndEngine Text example is working like charm now.

So, here are the steps I've done to get the AndEngine Text example working:
1- Go to the AndEngine Project (Source code you import to your game)
2- Go to class org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.java
3- Go to method: getFontManager()
4- Change the return value
From: return this.getFontManager();
To: return this.mEngine.getFontManager();

I hope this can be a help for anybody who has the same problem

Really appreciate the great effort from @*Nicolas Gramlich* for creating such an incredible game engine.

Thanks,
Mohamed.

Comment: I'm wondering why they don't add this bugfix into the source code at github?

Comment: Feel free to file a pull request =)